# Remove null values for only duplicate records

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to remove rows that are duplicated where the duplicated rows have a null value in one column, Y. I am ignoring rows that are not duplicated and have a null value in that same column, Y. Here is an example of the raw data:

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 1 | A | NULL |
| 2 | B | NULL |

The result of this SQL would be

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 2 | B | NULL |

I have considered create a column using `count() over ...` that determine if the row is duplicated and then using a `WHERE` clause to filter if the row is duplicated and there is a null value in Y, but I'm not sure that is the most efficient given this table is huge and we are trying to avoid helper columns.

What would be the most efficient approach here?

Comment: What would happen to records that are duplicated without a NULL in `Y`?  For example, using your example, the 2nd row of your raw table had a value in `Y` of 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a qualify filter to do this:

```
create or replace table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::int as "ID",
COLUMN2::string as "X",
COLUMN3::int as "Y"
from (values
(1,'A',5),
(1,'A',NULL),
(1,'A',6),
(2,'B',NULL),
(2,'B',NULL),
(3,'C',1)
);

select   ID, X, Y
from T1
qualify row_number() over (partition by ID, X order by null) = 1 or Y is not null
;
```

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 1 | A | 6 |
| 2 | B | null |
| 3 | C | 1 |